# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que las descargas de mi web utilicen https?

Tags: drupal8

Estoy administrando un sitio web que funciona con https. El problema es el siguiente:
El navegador Chrome, ahora bloquea las descargas con url http si la web es https.
Utilizo Drupal8 para gestionar este sitio y no encuentro la manera de hacer que los links de descarga de archivos, funcionen a través de https en vez de http.

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿No puedes cambiar los links de descarga? Por otro lado, te invito a repasar [ask] y [mcve]. Tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada porque necesita más detalles. Saludos

Comment: Te recomiendo mirar HSTS (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)

Answer (score 1):

La solución finalmente ha sido sencilla.

En la ruta donde tengas tu Drupal en /sites/default/settings.php

Hay una variable comentada:

```
# $settings['file_public_base_url'] = 'http://downloads.example.com/files';
```

La solución es desmarcarla y sustituir la URL de ejemplo por tu URL base de descargas y añadirle el https.